# Improves the time efficiency of query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that uses the subqueries for data. It takes a lot of time to run the query. How to improve the efficiency of the query.

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate date = '2021-12-06',
        @EndDate date = '2021-12-10',
        @VENDOR_SITE_ID int = '1034';

SELECT a.TARGET_DATE AS Date,
       b.TARGET_HOUR AS Time,
       b.AVAILABILITY,
       ISNULL((SELECT x.AVAILABILITY
               FROM CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER w
                    INNER JOIN CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL x ON x.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_FK = w.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_PK
               WHERE CONVERT(varchar(12), w.INTIMATION_DATE_TIME, 101) < CONVERT(varchar(12), w.TARGET_DATE, 101)
                 AND w.HOURLY_DATA_TYPE <> 'DAC'
                 AND DATEPART(HOUR, w.INTIMATION_DATE_TIME) BETWEEN '12' AND '19'
                 AND w.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK = a.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK
                 AND x.TARGET_HOUR = b.TARGET_HOUR
                 AND w.TARGET_DATE = a.TARGET_DATE
                 AND x.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL_ID_PK = (SELECT MAX(z.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL_ID_PK)
                                                         FROM CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER y
                                                              INNER JOIN CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL z ON z.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_FK = y.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_PK
                                                                                                        AND y.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK = w.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK
                                                                                                        AND y.HOURLY_DATA_TYPE = w.HOURLY_DATA_TYPE
                                                                                                        AND y.TARGET_DATE = w.TARGET_DATE
                                                                                                        AND z.TARGET_HOUR = x.TARGET_HOUR
                                                                                                        AND CONVERT(varchar(12), y.INTIMATION_DATE_TIME, 101) < CONVERT(varchar(12), y.TARGET_DATE, 101)
                                                                                                        AND DATEPART(HOUR, y.INTIMATION_DATE_TIME) BETWEEN '12' AND '19')),
              NULL) AS [DAC Revision-1],
       ISNULL((SELECT x.AVAILABILITY
               FROM CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER w
                    INNER JOIN CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL x ON x.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_FK = w.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_PK
               WHERE w.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK = a.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK
                 AND w.HOURLY_DATA_TYPE = 'ADAC'
                 AND w.TARGET_DATE = a.TARGET_DATE
                 AND x.TARGET_HOUR = b.TARGET_HOUR
                 AND CONVERT(varchar(12), w.INTIMATION_DATE_TIME, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(12), w.TARGET_DATE, 101)
                 AND x.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL_ID_PK = (SELECT MAX(z.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL_ID_PK)
                                                         FROM CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER y
                                                              INNER JOIN CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL z ON z.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_FK = y.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_PK
                                                         WHERE y.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK = w.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK
                                                           AND y.HOURLY_DATA_TYPE = w.HOURLY_DATA_TYPE
                                                           AND y.TARGET_DATE = w.TARGET_DATE
                                                           AND z.TARGET_HOUR = x.TARGET_HOUR
                                                           AND CONVERT(varchar(12), y.INTIMATION_DATE_TIME, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(12), y.TARGET_DATE, 101))),
              NULL) AS ADAC,
       ISNULL((SELECT x.AVAILABILITY
               FROM CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER w
                    INNER JOIN CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL x ON x.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_FK = w.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_PK
               WHERE w.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK = a.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK
                 AND w.HOURLY_DATA_TYPE = 'RDAC'
                 AND w.TARGET_DATE = a.TARGET_DATE
                 AND x.TARGET_HOUR = b.TARGET_HOUR
                 AND CONVERT(varchar(12), w.INTIMATION_DATE_TIME, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(12), w.TARGET_DATE, 101)
                 AND x.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL_ID_PK = (SELECT MAX(z.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL_ID_PK)
                                                         FROM CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER y
                                                              INNER JOIN CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL z ON z.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_FK = y.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_PK
                                                                                                        AND y.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK = w.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK
                                                                                                        AND y.HOURLY_DATA_TYPE = w.HOURLY_DATA_TYPE
                                                                                                        AND y.TARGET_DATE = w.TARGET_DATE
                                                                                                        AND z.TARGET_HOUR = x.TARGET_HOUR
                                                                                                        AND CONVERT(varchar(12), y.INTIMATION_DATE_TIME, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(12), y.TARGET_DATE, 101))),
              NULL) AS RDAC,
       ISNULL((SELECT x.AVAILABILITY
               FROM CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER w
                    INNER JOIN CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL x ON x.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_FK = w.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_PK
               WHERE w.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK = a.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK
                 AND w.TARGET_DATE = a.TARGET_DATE
                 AND x.TARGET_HOUR = b.TARGET_HOUR
                 AND x.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL_ID_PK = (SELECT MAX(z.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL_ID_PK)
                                                         FROM CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER y
                                                              INNER JOIN CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL z ON z.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_FK = y.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_PK
                                                                                                        AND y.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK = w.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK
                                                                                                        AND y.TARGET_DATE = w.TARGET_DATE
                                                                                                        AND z.TARGET_HOUR = x.TARGET_HOUR)),
              NULL) AS Final
FROM CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER a
     INNER JOIN CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL b ON b.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_FK = a.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER_ID_PK
     INNER JOIN CDXP.AP_SUPPLIER_SITE_ALL c ON a.VENDOR_SITE_ID_FK = c.VENDOR_SITE_ID
                                           AND c.VENDOR_SITE_ID = @VENDOR_SITE_ID
WHERE a.HOURLY_DATA_TYPE = 'DAC'
  AND a.TARGET_DATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
ORDER BY 'Date',
         'Time';
```

How to minimize the running time of such type of queries. Need help

Comment: All those subqueries in a subquery in the `SELECT` is likely going to be awful for performance. Your aliasing could also be significantly better. `a` *and* `w` are for `WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER`? `b` and `x` are for `WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL`? The latter doesn't have a `b` or `x` in it's name, so why those your alias choices?

Comment: You could try `outer apply` in stead of subqueries, but to know if it makes a difference we need more information

Comment: Honestly, I would suggest that instead you provide us with some sample data, expected results and explain your goal; I don't doubt that the above attempt is vastly overly complicated.

Comment: a b are used in main query, whereas w and x are used in subquery and y and z are used in sub sub-query

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Please provide  a schema, including indexing, sample data and expected results, as well as an EXPLAIN for your current query. WIthout that, we're just guessing.

Comment: How does I define my data in the tables. It's complex and I'm confuse to explain

Comment: Schema name CDXP and the tables name are CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_HEADER and CDXP.WP_GC_HOURLY_DATA_DETAIL.

Comment: Any suggestion of reducing sub queries?

Comment: Maybe you should use window function (`row_number()`) and filter on it instead on finding max(id) and joining corresponding row by all attributes - it may help somewhat. Of course date conversions (noted in @SQLpro answer) are likely to affect performance more.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you will convert any data from one datatype to another, no index will be used.

For this reason, do not write :

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), w.INTIMATION_DATE_TIME, 101) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), w.TARGET_DATE, 101)
```

To have only the date part of a datetime. Use a CAST to the DATE datatype instead :

```
CAST(w.INTIMATION_DATE_TIME AS DATE) < CAST(w.TARGET_DATE AS DATE)
```

Then indexes will be used

Comment: Relevant: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: Nothing happened, same time.